# How to display pages linked to a specific category using Wordpress REST API?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api

I am accessing the JSON from a url but it returns me only the JSON containing all the categories on the site. I don't know how to capture the pages linked to this category.

I'm using JavaScript with a search function to call a wordpress API, it displays the result with the page id on the console:

```
    fetch('https://novoportal.cemig.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/categorias_cemig_atende?slug=servicos', {'method': 'GET'}).then((response) => {
  return response.json()
}).then((data) => {
  // console.log(data);

  const obj = JSON.stringify(data);

  const j = JSON.parse(obj);
  console.log(j);

  data.forEach((posts) => {
    /*console.log(movie.title);
    console.log(movie.description);*/
    console.log(posts.slug);
  });
}).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

How to show the pages of a specific category?